# Sidekiq delay method not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm adding Sidekiq into my Rails 4 app (not doing anything with `perform_async`), and when I `delay` a job, in my case mailing something, Rails complains that there is no method named `delay`. This is what I'm calling:

`MyMailer.delay.signup_notification(@user.id, @user.email)`

I've added the gem and saw that `bundle install` listed the gem (using sidekiq 2.11.0), I'm developing locally and running `bundle exec sidekiq` along with a Redis server locally on 127.0.0.1:6379 (default port 6379).

Why is Sidekiq's method definition not found? A weird thing also is that RubyMine can jump to the definition, but when I run Rails, it gives the error that `delay` is not found. I see in Sidekiq's definition that it's supposed to extend `delay` to every class.

Comment: Is it included in a particular gem group that is perhaps not included in whatever environment you're attempting to use it?

Comment: I'm using a Rails engine that uses sidekiq. The engine includes sidekiq in all environments. Turns out I needed to include sidekiq in my app as well as in the engine (I find that odd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `gem "sidekiq"` in console. If it returns true, try running this snippet:

```
class TestMailer < ActionMailer::Base; def x; end; end; TestMailer.delay
```

You should get some output back from Redis.

If the first command fails, you're not including `sidekiq` properly in your `Gemfile`. If the second command fails, you're doing something weird in your `MyMailer` class.

Remember, if you're running Rails console in the `development` environment (if you don't know, you probably are, but you can check with `Rails.env`) you'll need to let `development` have access to the gem in the `Gemfile`.

Comment: I'm using a Rails engine, which is the thing that uses sidekiq. The engine included sidekiq in its gemfile, so I assumed if I included the engine, it would include sidekiq as well. This turns out to not be the case. I fixed it by adding sidekiq to my app in addition to it already being in the engine. Thanks for helping debug!

Answer (score 3):

Just had something similar... but triggered by a Sidekiq update.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions says,

> They are disabled by default in Sidekiq 5+. Use
>   Sidekiq::Extensions.enable_delay! to turn them on.

Add Sidekiq::Extensions.enable_delay! to the initializer